# How to modify input-text class in the login- page to change font?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm trying to change the font to Arial on the login text input and at the same time remove the all cap style.

Under `../app/design/frontend/<YOUR_THEME>/Magento_Customer/templates/form/`
I can see

```
<div class="control">
<input name="login[username]"
   value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getUsername()) ?>"
   id="email" type="email" class="input-text" title="<?php echo __('Email') ?>"
   data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}" placeholder="<?php echo __
('Email')
?>">
```

however I don't know where I to modify input-text class or if this is even the correct thing to do to change the font for this field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you if you want to change the font family only of this field or for all your website.

To change the font family of this field to Arial is not necessary to add a class, you can simply do something like

```
.login-container .block-content input.input-text {
    font-family: Arial;
}
```